# Access adds a new record when choosing from a combo box

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a subform for a line of an invoice (invoiceLine) and in that subform, I have a combo box that lets you choose the serviceName that goes on that line. However, when I choose a serviceName from the combo box, instead of using the service record that's already there, it adds a new record in my Service table and places the serviceID from the serviceName I selected in the serviceName column.

For example, if I choose "Editing" in the combo box as the serviceName, instead of using the serviceID for "Editing" in the InvoiceLine table, it creates a whole new Service record with a serviceName being the serviceID of "Editing" and a brand new serviceID for this record.

The combo box I'm talking about has "Control Source" set to serviceName, "Row Source" is

```
SELECT Service.serviceID, Service.serviceName,Service.serviceCurrentPricePerHour FROM Service;
```

and the "After Update" attribute has a "SearchForRecord" set with "Record" being First and the "Where Condition" is

```
="[servID] = " & Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))
```

Service Table

```
serviceID
serviceName
serviceCurrentPricePerHour
serviceDescription
```

InvoiceLine table

```
invoiceLineID
serviceID
priceActuallyChargedPerHour
invoiceID
hoursWorked
```

Invoice table

```
invoiceID
invoiceDate
customerID
projectName
invoiceDiscount
```

Comment: Please clarify:  You say that the comboBox Control Source is set to serviceName, yet the Row Source first column is serviceID.  That is not necessarily a problem (or the cause of the weird behavior), but usually the first column of the Row Source matches the bound property so that the correct value from the list is actually saved in the bound column.  Please update question with values of [Bound Column], [Column Count] and [Column Widths] properties.

Comment: Is the form RecordSource a query that includes InvoiceLine and Service tables? There is no need to include Service table and I suspect that is source of issue. Combobox Control Source should be serviceID field from InvoiceLine table not InvoiceName of Service table.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the control source, when you change it it creates a NewRecord.